# ReferenceError: function is not defined

Tags: javascript, php

I am new to coding php and javascript. After putting this changeContent function in my code it is not finding it. Displaying a reference error, i think it has something to do with the "//" in the links. How would I go about fixing it?

```
    <?php
    $one =  "<iframe src='http://www.google.com' width='100%' height='84%'      frameborder='0'></iframe>";
    $two = "<iframe src='http://www.facebook.com' width='100%' height='84%'    frameborder='0'></iframe>";
    $three = "<iframe src='http://www.youtube.com' width='100%' height='84%' frameborder='0'></iframe>";
    echo "
    <html xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml'     xmlns:fb='http://developers.facebook.com/schema/' version='XHTML+RDFa 1.0' xml:lang='en'
    <head>

    <link type='text/css' rel='stylesheet' href='style.css'/>

    <script type='text/javascript'> 
    function changeContent() { 
    document.getElementById('content').innerHTML='<?=$one?>';
    } 
    </script> 
    <script type='text/javascript'>
    function changeContent2() { 
    document.getElementById('content').innerHTML='<iframe src='<?=$two?>' width='100%'                 height='84%' frameborder='0'></iframe>'; 
    } 
    </script> 
    <script type='text/javascript'>
    function changeContent3() { 
    document.getElementById('content').innerHTML='<iframe src='<?$three?>' width='100%'         height='84%' frameborder='0'></iframe></iframe>';
    } 
    </script>
    </head>

    <body>

    <div id='topplace'>
    <ul>
    <li><a href='#' class='classname' onClick=\"changeContent()\">google <small         class='button'>Test</small></a></li>
    <li>&nbsp;</li>
    <li><a href='#' class='classname' onClick=\"changeContent2()\">facebook <small         class='button'>Test</small></a></li>
    <li>&nbsp;</li>
    <li><a href='#' class='classname' onClick=\"changeContent3()\">youtube <small class='button'>test</small></a></li>
    </ul>
    </div>

    </body>";
    ?>
```

Comment: You'll probably get a big hint if you look at the actual generated HTML page (e.g. use View/Source in the browser).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Also, you should change `$one/$two/$three` values just to URLs.

And

```
 .innerHTML='<iframe
```

needs to be changed to

```
 .innerHTML=\"<iframe
```

to make JS work

Comment: Also needed to add this Thanks too!

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using string concatination,

so you don't need to use this withing string `<?=$one?>`

Instead write this way $one or you can preffer `{$one}`

Answer (score 0):

echo long string is not a good idea, use include instead.

```
<?php
$one =  "<iframe src='http://www.google.com' width='100%' height='84%'  frameborder='0'></iframe>";
$two = "<iframe src='http://www.facebook.com' width='100%' height='84%'    frameborder='0'></iframe>";
$three = "<iframe src='http://www.youtube.com' width='100%' height='84%' frameborder='0'></iframe>";
include ('view.php');
```

view.php

```
<html xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml'
    xmlns:fb='http://developers.facebook.com/schema/'
    version='XHTML+RDFa 1.0' xml:lang='en'>

<head>

<link type='text/css' rel='stylesheet' href='style.css' />

<script type='text/javascript'> 
    function changeContent() { 
    document.getElementById('content').innerHTML='<?=addslashes($one)?>';
    } 
    </script>
<script type='text/javascript'>
    function changeContent2() { 
    document.getElementById('content').innerHTML='<?=addslashes($two)?>'; 
    } 
    </script>
<script type='text/javascript'>
    function changeContent3() { 
    document.getElementById('content').innerHTML='<?=addslashes($three)?>';
    } 
    </script>
</head>

<body>

    <div id="content"></div>

    <div id='topplace'>
        <ul>
            <li><a href='#' class='classname' onClick="changeContent()">google <small
                    class='button'>Test</small>
            </a></li>
            <li>&nbsp;</li>
            <li><a href='#' class='classname' onClick="changeContent2()">facebook
                    <small class='button'>Test</small>
            </a></li>
            <li>&nbsp;</li>
            <li><a href='#' class='classname' onClick="changeContent3()">youtube
                    <small class='button'>test</small>
            </a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>

</body></html>
```

<strike>Change from</strike>

```
'<iframe src='<?=$two?>' width='100%'
```

To

```
//no <?=, and make change ' to \"
'<iframe src=\"$two\" width=\"100%\"
```